# How to convert my finished app?

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

I would like to know how i can convert finished application created in Universal Windows Platform to Android? Can i convert code ? Or is this doing with any applications? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no automated tool for this. Assuming your UWP app was created with C# and XAML you could look at using Xamarin.Forms to create an app that works on both platforms and is based on your current app.

Sorry, a full guide on how to do this is beyond a simple answer here and out of scope for this site.

Comment: Okay. So i do not have to write this big code again but i can do in Xamarin to both platforms and is based on my current app?? Thank you

Comment: so i do not have to write this big code again???? Plase answer me :-)